# Accept rates no longer being displayed

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

I notice that *accept rates* are no longer being displayed under the questioner's user name. Does anybody know why this has been done?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate/164654#164654

Comment: Peripherally related http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3544/should-users-be-asked-to-increase-their-accept-rates

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the Meta Stack Overflow site which covers the entire Stack Exchange network, a [recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) asked for accept rates to stop being displayed. The poster wrote:

> But as long as you're displaying the accept rate, people will comment on it, criticize users for it and possibly reconsider answering because of it. And while I'm of the opinion that a low accept rate should not stop you from answering (we're here to make the internet better after all) and that the possible reputation gain (or lack thereof) should not factor in either, I can't blame users for considering it. It's in their face after all. And we're only people.
>
> So let's take the issue off the table. Or at least partially. Information about a user's acceptance behavior can still always be gathered from the profile. But at least that would be less in-your-face.
>
> "But it helps me to see if a user is a help vampire!"
>   I'm still wondering if those are of the sparkly variety as well, but I digress. So what? If the question is bad, downvote it. Evaluate a question on its individual value. There is no need to take a user's history into account. There might be a correlation between the quality of a question and a user's accept rate, but there doesn't have to be. And if there is, the bigger problem is the question's quality.
>
> "Exactly! A user with a low accept rate might indicate there's a problem!"
>   I'm not arguing we should get rid of the accept-rate value within SO/SE. After all, this Q&A works based on up and downvotes, as well as the acceptance of an answer. But why not use it behind the scenes to (very occasionally) nudge the user with a statement like:
>
> "You have received several answers to your questions, yet have not accepted an answer as correct or helpful in a while. You might want to evaluate them and where possible accept them as correct or helpful".
>
> After all, in the various questions with regards to comments on low accept rates, if any comments are encouraged at all, then they are of this soft variety. So why not let the system take care of that?

The change was made in the most recent build of the site. Accept rate is no longer shown because the negative consequences outweigh the benefits.

Comment: Hopefully, the build also includes notices being sent to unenlightened users to accept answers. Thank you, Simchona.